# rCharts and javascript: only a fraction of entries is plotted

Tags: javascript, r, rcharts

Whenever I plot >1000 entries using rCharts and open the output in browser, only part of the datapoints are plotted. Each time I refresh the page, random datapoints (from those included in the data frame) are being shown. 
Is there any way to include all the entries? I am totally new to R and scripts, but guess it's a javascript issue?

```
data = data.frame(sample(1:10,size = 10000, replace = TRUE), rnorm(10000))
colnames(data)=c("x","y")
p1 <- rPlot("x", "y", data = data, type = 'point')
p1$save("p1.html")
```

rChart output uses the [polychart2.standalone.js](https://raw.github.com/Polychart/polychart2/develop/polychart2.standalone.js) script.

Thanks for help!

Comment: It is a bug in Polycharts. See [here](https://github.com/Polychart/polychart2/issues/4).

Comment: Thanks Ramnath.
It's highly unfortunate, as it leaves me with no nice tool to plot big data with convenient labeling. And the one you've implemented in rCharts is pretty outstanding.
Is there any workaround or alternative?

Comment: By labelling you mean hover? If yes, then rCharts supports other libraries which can show all points. See [here](http://rcharts.io/viewer/?7156866).

Comment: Code for the previous plot is `p1 <- nPlot("x", "y", data = data, type = 'scatterChart')`

Comment: Yes, indeed. Specifically, I meant tooltips.
I've got it working with
`p1$chart(tooltipContent = "#! function(key, x, y, e){ 
 return 'tip: ' + e.point.interakcja 
 } !#")`
Hope I use it properly. Thanks Ramnath!

Comment: Should I post my comment as an answer so that you can accept it and close this question?

Comment: Yes, of course. nvd3 is even better to visualise my data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation to the OP (from my comment) was to use NVD3. The code for `tooltipContent` is from the OP.

```
p1 <- nPlot("x", "y", data = data, type = 'scatterChart')
p1$chart(tooltipContent = "#! function(key, x, y, e){ 
  return 'tip: ' + e.point.interakcja 
} !#")
```